# foaf and count in a sparql 1.1 query

Tags: sparql

I'm a beginner in SPARQL, so it would be great if you could help me. . I have a RDF doc like this:

```
  @prefix foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/> .
  @prefix lb:   <http://example.org/lastfm/> .

  lb:bob     foaf:knows      lb:user2, lb:user3, lb:user4 ;
       foaf:age        25 ;
       lb:listenedTo   lb:track1, lb:track2 ;
       lb:topArtist    lb:artist1, lb:artist2 .        

  lb:user2   foaf:knows      lb:user5, lb:user6 ;
       foaf:age        40 ;
       lb:listenedTo   lb:track1, lb:track2, lb:track3 ;  
       lb:topArtist    lb:artist2, lb:artist4 .        

  lb:user3   foaf:knows      lb:user5, lb:bob, lb:user6 ;
       foaf:age        19 ;
       lb:listenedTo   lb:track2, lb:track3, lb:track4 ;
       lb:topArtist    lb:artist2, lb:artist3 .      

  lb:user4   lb:listenedTo   lb:track2, lb:track3, lb:track4 ;
       foaf:age        61 ;
       lb:topArtist    lb:artist3, lb:artist4, lb:artist5 .     

  lb:user5   foaf:knows      lb:user7 ;
       foaf:age        23 ;
       lb:topArtist    lb:artist1, lb:artist3 .
```

and I want to find all users that can be reached from `lb:bob` by following the `foaf:knows` at most 3 times and who have listened to at least two tracks. I wrote a query like this:

```
  PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
  prefix foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
  prefix lb:   <http://example.org/lastfm/>

  select ?user
  where
  {
   lb:bob foaf:knows | foaf:knows/foaf:knows| foaf:knows/foaf:knows/foaf:knows ?user.
    ?user lb:listenedTo ?tracks
     minus{lb:bob lb:listenedTo ?track}
      filter (?tracks count(*)>=2)
  }
```

but this error:

```
Encountered " "count" "count "" at line 12, column 23. Was expecting one of:
 "not" ...
 "in" ...
 <INTEGER_POSITIVE> ...
 <DECIMAL_POSITIVE> ...
 <DOUBLE_POSITIVE> ...
 <INTEGER_NEGATIVE> ...
 <DECIMAL_NEGATIVE> ...
 <DOUBLE_NEGATIVE> ...
 ")" ...
 "=" ...
 "!=" ...
 ">" ...
 "<" ...
 "<=" ...
 ">=" ...
 "||" ...
 "&&" ...
 "+" ...
 "-" ...
 "*" ...
 "/" ...
```

I know that my query has a lot of problems, would you please rewrite it for me?

Comment: Hi, thank you .                                                         Encountered " "count" "count "" at line 12, column 23.
Was expecting one of:
    "not" ...
    "in" ...
    <INTEGER_POSITIVE> ...
    <DECIMAL_POSITIVE> ...
    <DOUBLE_POSITIVE> ...
    <INTEGER_NEGATIVE> ...
    <DECIMAL_NEGATIVE> ...
    <DOUBLE_NEGATIVE> ...
    ")" ...
    "=" ...
    "!=" ...
    ">" ...
    "<" ...
    "<=" ...
    ">=" ...
    "||" ...
    "&&" ...
    "+" ...
    "-" ...
    "*" ...
    "/" ...

Answer (score 5):

How about:

```
prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
prefix foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
prefix lb:   <http://example.org/lastfm/>

select ?user
where
{
  lb:bob foaf:knows | foaf:knows/foaf:knows| foaf:knows/foaf:knows/foaf:knows ?user.
  ?user lb:listenedTo ?tracks
}
group by ?user
having (count(?tracks) > 2)
```

You have `minus` in the original query that I'm not sure about. Are you trying to remove `lb:bob` as a binding for `?user`, perhaps? `filter (?user != lb:bob)` would stop that.

Comment: +1 Aggregate expressions cannot be used inside of a `FILTER`, if you need to filter using an aggregate you must do it within a `HAVING` clause as this answer shows